# Datadog monitor with if-else condition

Tags: datadog

I would like to create a Datadog Monitor Alert based on the following scenario:

I have two logs that happen at the same time:

- (A) `@msg:"Processed"`
- (B) `@msg:"Some files not processed"`

Well, to my monitor state changes to error it should obey the following condition: `Log B MUST exist at least 1 time and Log B MUST NOT exist`.

I didn't find a way to create this condition in **Datadog Monitor**, I tried with  **Composite Monitor** but the problem with composite is that single alerts are triggered at different times causing false positives to me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you count the occurance of each log line as seperate queries in a Log Monitor and then create a formula to find the difference between them?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I thought about it too, I just want to know if there is a way to create a kinda `if-else` statement on the monitor. But seems like not.